# How to get a all rows data but specific columns only in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How to get a all rows data but specific columns only in datatables?

```
let h = customerTable.rows().columns([0,2,3,4,5]).data(function(d){
                if(d === 'PETRON GASUL 50 KILOS'){
                    d = "1";
                }
            }).toArray();
console.log(h);
```

I am trying to get all the rows but specific columns but the result is like this

```
0: (2) ['SINV-zpEtZRO2', 'SINV-zpEtZRO2']
1: (2) ['PETRON GASUL 50 KILOS', 'PETRON GASUL 2.7 KILOS Compact-Valve Type ("de salpak")']
2: (2) ['REFILL', 'REFILL']
3: (2) ['1', '1']
4: (2) ['3381', '322']
```

I want it to be an array per row but a specific columns only...

Comment: could you please edit your question adding part of the original data as an example, thanks